# Problem with a task of printing inward triangle with stars

Tags: printing

```
public class TulosteluaLikeABoss {

    public static void tulostaTahtia(int maara) {
        // part 1
        int i = 0;
        while (maara >i) {

            System.out.print("*");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }

    public static void tulostaTyhjaa(int maara) {
        // part 1.1
        int i = 0;
        while (maara > i) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            i++;
        }
    }
    //something is wrong below
    public static void tulostaKolmio(int koko) {
        // part 2
        
        int j = koko;
        int k = 0;
        while (koko >= k) {

            tulostaTahtia(k);
            
            tulostaTyhjaa(j);
            k++;
            j = j-1;
        }
    }
    // from here below is irrelevant
    public static void jouluKuusi(int korkeus) {
        // part 3
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Testit eivät katso main-metodia, voit muutella tätä vapaasti.

        tulostaKolmio(5);
        System.out.println("---");
        jouluKuusi(4);
        System.out.println("---");
        jouluKuusi(10);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do a Java basics course and the task is to print an inward triangle using stars *

I got my program to print that, but when I try to submit, I get error message saying: When tried to call method tulostaKolmio(1), wrong amount of lines were printed.  expected <1> but was <2>. I'm pretty annoyed by this, since I ran the code using tulostaKolmio(1) and the program printed just 1 line that had 1 star like it was supposed to. If the code looks strange it's because this is a 3 part task and I'm only doing the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tulostaKolmio(1) assigns koko the value of 1. The while loop in the method will run (koko + 1) number of times. During the first run in the loop tulostaTahita(0) gets called (since k=0 right now), altough it will not print any starts at this call it will print a new line because you have that outside the while loop in the tulostaTahita method.

During the second run in the loop, k=1 and thus tulostaTahita(1) is called. This will print another line so in the end you are left with 2 lines (where the first one is empty).

To solve this you want to add an if statement to make sure tulostaTahita only prints a new line when maara is greater than 0.